# Select all data when passing parameters with null

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2012. This is my stored procedure code:

```
select * 
from tbl_Events te
where te.MainEventID = ISNULL(@EventID, te.MainEventID)
  and te.EventCityID = ISNULL(@CityID, te.EventCityID)
  and te.OwnerPassNo = ISNULL(@PassNo, te.OwnerPassNo)
  and te.[Owner] LIKE '%' + @Owner + '%'
  and te.isActive = 'true'
```

When I try to execute it with the following

```
exec sp_GetEvents @Owner=N''
```

it returns 0 rows, though I have some data in my table.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any data with owner as blank string - '', my take no so you get 0 rows.

Comment: @Abhishek nope I don't

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is using the sp_ prefix. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix You should choose another prefix, or even better no prefix at all.

Comment: To help with your issue it would be helpful to have more than just some code. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: *Don't* use such queries. They result in very bad performance because the server will cache and reuse the execution plan used the *first* time the query was executed

Comment: Here is an excellent article discussing the performance problems of this type of thing with some great solution ideas. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/

Comment: `@Owner=N''` does not mean `@Owner IS NULL` it means @Owner is an empty string, SQL Server null is null and not an empty string.

Comment: @SeanLange I don't have them all bookmarked. In fact, I was getting ready to post this one https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/

Comment: @SeanLange wait ... it's the same article, different blog??

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes indeed. You posted a link to Gail's blog where I posted the version that was published on SSC. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select * from tbl_Events te
    where 
    (@EventID IS NULL OR te.MainEventID = @EventID) AND
    (@CityID IS NULL OR te.EventCityID = @CityID) AND
    (@PassNo IS NULL OR te.OwnerPassNo = @PassNo) AND
    te.[Owner] like '%' + @Owner + '%' AND
    te.isActive = 'true'
```

And check if 'isActive' expects 'true' or 1

Comment: This is basically the same thing as the original query, just a more verbose way of getting there.